# ¿Cómo transformar valores binarios textuales en int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una columna `loan_status` en una dataframe que contiene `Fully Paid` o `Charged Off` y me gustaria transformarla en 1 o 0.

```
    int_rate    installment dti     revol_bal   revol_util  inq_last_6mths  delinq_2yrs pub_rec loan_status purpose_credit_card purpose_debt_consolidation  purpose_home_improvement    purpose_house   purpose_major_purchase  purpose_medical purpose_moving  purpose_other   purpose_renewable_energy    purpose_small_business  purpose_vacation    purpose_wedding
11  14.07%      233.05     24.69    707         15.7%       0               0               0   Fully Paid  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  11.98%      232.44     20.25    5004        36%         0               0               0   Fully Paid  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  26.77%      607.97     24.40    7364        46%         1               0               0   Charged Off 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

¿Sabes cómo puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas posibles, pero una muy simple es usar `pandas.Series.map`:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"loan_status": ["Fully Paid", "Charged Off",
                                   "Fully Paid", "Fully Paid", "Charged Off"]
                   })
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    loan_status
> 0   Fully Paid
> 1  Charged Off
> 2   Fully Paid
> 3   Fully Paid
> 4  Charged Off
> ```

```
df["loan_status"] = df["loan_status"].map({"Fully Paid": 1, "Charged Off": 0})
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    loan_status
> 0            1
> 1            0
> 2            1
> 3            1
> 4            0
> ```

`pandas.Series.map` genera una nueva serie, en la que cada elemento de la original es buscado en el diccionario pasado como argumento y substituido por su valor asociado.

Otra posibilidad podría ser usar `np.where`:

```
df["loan_status"] = np.where(df["loan_status"] == "Fully Paid", 1, 0)
```

Otra alternativa es `pandas.Series.replace` como @ThePassenger comenta abajo:

```
df["loan_status"] = df["loan_status"].replace(["Fully Paid", "Charged Off"], [1, 0])
```

o mejor, inplace:

```
df["loan_status"].replace(["Fully Paid", "Charged Off"], [1, 0], inplace=True)
```

Un pequeño test de tiempos de ejecución usando una serie de 50000 elementos:

> **`pandas.Series.map`**: 4.05 ms ± 39.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>   **`np.where`**: 3.79 ms ± 52.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>   **`pandas.Series.replace`**: 12.3 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: utilicé `.replace(['truc','troc'],[1,0])`

Comment: La pregunta no está relacionada, pero ¿sabe cómo convertir clumna de string de porcentaje en float?

Comment: Si, `pandas.Series.str.replace` es otra forma. En cuanto a lo del porcentaje, es sencillo hacerlo, pero se pude hacer al leer el csv directamente o una vez leido. Si no te importa crea otra pregunta con esta duda, puede ser interesante para otros usuarios.

Comment: Si, lo hicé [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280021/c%c3%b3mo-convertir-clumna-de-string-de-porcentaje-en-float)