# ¿Cómo convertir clumna de string de porcentaje en float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una dataframe con porcentajes que son de formato objeto.
Pero, tratando de hacer una regresión lineal, los necesito para flotar. ¿Sabeis cómo puedo hacer?

```
    int_rate    installment dti     revol_bal   revol_util  inq_last_6mths  delinq_2yrs pub_rec loan_status purpose_credit_card purpose_debt_consolidation  purpose_home_improvement    purpose_house   purpose_major_purchase  purpose_medical purpose_moving  purpose_other   purpose_renewable_energy    purpose_small_business  purpose_vacation    purpose_wedding
11  14.07%      233.05     24.69    707         15.7%       0               0               0   Fully Paid  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  11.98%      232.44     20.25    5004        36%         0               0               0   Fully Paid  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  26.77%      607.97     24.40    7364        46%         1               0               0   Charged Off 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Tal vez puede ser interesente, el dataframe proviene de un csv. Oido que podemos filtrar estos datos en la fuente.

Pueden descargar el csv [aquí](https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action) (préstamos bancarios para 2018. Se dividen en cuatro trimestres). Usando Python 3 se puede obtener haciendo:

```
import pandas as pd 
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data_Q1 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q1.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q2 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q3 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q4 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
frames = [data_Q1,data_Q2,data_Q3,data_Q4]

result = pd.concat(frames)
subset = result.loc[result["loan_status"].isin(['Charged Off','Fully Paid'])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenemos varias posibilidades:

- Si lees los datos desde un archivo csv, puedes usar el argumento `converters` al que le pasas un diccionario en el que la clave es el nombre de la columna y el valor una función a usar para convertir el valor.

  ```
  import io
  import pandas as pd

  data = io.StringIO("""
  int_rate    revol_bal
    14.07%          707
    11.98%         5004
    26.77%         7364
   """)

  df = pd.read_csv(data,
                   sep="\s+",
                   converters={'int_rate': lambda x: float(x.rstrip("%"))}
                   )
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> df
  >
  >    int_rate  revol_bal
  > 0     14.07        707
  > 1     11.98       5004
  > 2     26.77       7364
  > ```
- Si no obtenemos los datos de un csv, una vez creada la columna puedes hacer lo mismo usando `pandas.Series.rstrip` y una conversión de tipo con el método `pandas.Series.astype`:

  ```
  df["int_rate"] = df["int_rate"].str.rstrip('%').astype('float')
  ```

En ambos casos la idea es la misma, usar `str.rsplit` para eliminar todo carácter % que exista a la derecha de la cadena. Hecho esto procedemos a hacer el casting al tipo deseado.

Si tenemos algún espacio intermedio (`"14.2 %"`), podemos usar `rsplit` dos veces o mejor, usar `str.replace`:

```
df["int_rate"] = df["int_rate"].str.translate(str.maketrans({"%": "", " ": ""})).astype(float)
```

Comment: ¿Y qué pasa si la columna no es de formato de cadena sino de formato de objeto? De hecho tuve el error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: Tu columna no es de tipo `str`, es un tipo nativo de NumPy. Que obteines si haces `df["columna"]. types`... Tiene pinta de que la columna ya es de tipo float o int... Asegurate también de estar aplicando la conversión a la columna correcta.

Comment: En mi ejemplo si haces `df["revol_bal"].str.rstrip('%').astype('float')` obtienes el error que comentas, dado que `revol_balrevol` es de tipo entero. Si tu columna tiene % es de tipo object (str) seguro, o intentas convertir una columna equivocada o intentas aplicar la conversión dos veces.